# what is simple meaning of the philosophical term ''Categorical Imperative''?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning, terminology

About following definition given by Marriam Webster dictionary, May I know a clear and simple meaning? or simple meaning of the term ''Categorical Imperative''?
Because I'm not clear enough as its definition: it is difficult to take its meaning simply.

**Categorical Imperative**:
a moral obligation or command that is unconditionally and universally binding.

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What confuses you about the given definition?

Comment: I'm not clear enough its meaning. Thanks...

Comment: Which words or phrases are you confused about? We can't help you if we don't know what problems you have with Merriam-Webster's accurate definition. Do you know the meaning of "moral"? "obligation"? "moral obligation"? "unconditionally"? "universally"? "binding"? Help us out!

Comment: yes. the words:  ''unconditionally'', ''binding'' and '' universally'' are confused me .

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because I don't see an "English Learning" question here.  There is an interesting question in [philosophy.se].  The technical term "categorical imperative" is not a common idiom of general English.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to understand the etymology and to know the one most famous example.

The term "categorical" here comes from logic. A "categorical proposition" is a statement of the form "A is B" or "A is not B". It simply asserts or denies a predicate (the "B") about a subject (the "A"). For example, "The sky is cloudy." A "hypothetical proposition" says "If P, then Q" where P and Q are themselves propositions. The hypothetical proposition doesn't assert Q *categorically*: it asserts Q only on the condition that P is true. For example, "If it's raining now, the sky is cloudy." Another type of proposition is "disjunctive": "Either P is true or Q is true but not both."

"Imperative" is an adjective that comes from the Latin word for "command". In "categorical imperative", the word "imperative" is used substantively, i.e. as a noun. It means a proposition that tells you what to do—not a description, but a command. Most imperatives are hypothetical: "If you want to become rich, then *save money.*" "If you want to wake up early, then *go to bed early.*"

The German philosopher Immanuel Kant first proposed the concept of a "categorical imperative" in his book *[Groundwork of the Metaphysics of Morals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundwork_of_the_Metaphysics_of_Morals)* (1785). A categorical imperative would be a duty that you should perform not as a means to some other end, as in a hypothetical imperative. Kant argued that all moral principles have at their root a single categorical imperative:

> Act only in accordance with that maxim through which you can at the same time will that it become a universal law.

Or, stated more plainly, "Whatever moral principles you go by, they must apply equally to everyone else." Or, loosely, "Do unto others as you would have them do unto you."

Comment: Do unto others as you would have them do unto you= treat others, as treat yourself? ?? Thanks...

Comment: @SakyaKim It means to treat others as you want them to treat you.